Connection help for DC-DC converter R2D-0524
I want to use R2D-0524 in my circuit, I will input a voltage of 5V to it, and expect to produce ±24V output. But I am confused about its COM pin.
This is the link for this converter.(https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/RECOM-Power/R2D-0524?qs=XF8hdbuHJAVn2ofamRUaXw%3D%3D&srsltid=AfmBOorglQRDyVbBqYkBP8E2SS5T9LCdPkJJeq9__ELCEdpEMvaJ_OXs)
The manual does not mark the COM pins, and connects +Vin to +Vout and -Vin to -Vout.
The following is the schematic I drew in Alitum. I did not connect the input to the output through a capacitor. I used COM as the midpoint of ±Vout and connected them together. I want to know if my connection is correct? I am eager to get your help. Thank you very much.

Based on the responses I received, I updated my new circuit diagram. Can you guys help me check if it is correct and if any further changes are required?


It looks like you referred to the R2S pinout instead of the R2D, which shows COM.
No safety and filtering setup is shown for the dual R2D-xxxx, which is necessary for a dual supply. The lack of balanced safety capacitors can lead to issues if your load has unbalanced AC or input capacitance. These imbalances can introduce common mode noise, affecting high-impedance inputs.
To address this, use balanced 300 pF safety capacitors. This helps couple low differential RF impedance on the 5V source to the +/-12V differential output, reducing noise ingress.
For safety, you need measures against over-voltage, EMI, and possible high-voltage faults (like ESD or lightning transients). Ensure adequate isolation and attenuation, with up to 60 dB of isolation from the source. If your 5V source lacks a PE ground, add a 1 nF to 5 nF cap or directly couple COM to PE ground to reduce ripple impact on your load signals.
For stable performance, use an input choke and a 10 µF capacitor to filter dynamic load ripple, avoiding resonance and cross-talk by removing C2 at the input filter (as shown in table).
A floating setup can lead to issues later. For instance, floating 5V USB supplies can inject common mode noise into connected laptops, causing USB data corruption unless the charger is DC to PE grounded via tower PC.
For analog circuits with critical load regulation, adding these filters can help manage load-regulated ripple and improve stability.  This happens when dual peripherals also use an isolated DC supply with two isolated SMPS supplies injecting SMPS ripple CM noise onto slightly unbalanced USB cables creating a differential (DM) ripple on the data causing comm. failure.
For safety, the isolation option with a /H suffix for 3 kV-rating is preferred (or 1 kV if isolation isn’t a major concern).
Using your linked datasheet... I have marked up my recommendations.


Hi, thanks a lot for your help. I updated my circuit in my question, could you help me check if it is correct and if further modifications are needed? Thanks a lot.

it is logically same as mine but not as pretty. ;)  try to use std symbols and fewer crossed signals and same labels like COM,  define PE connections if any

Thanks for your reply, so my current circuit connection is correct? Do I need to connect +Vout and -Vout to COM separately through capacitors? I saw in your answer that this is not done.

No they are optimized internally, So just film or NP0 at load for small dI/dt using parasitic ESL on bus.  Correct but not pretty.  10uH choke symbols are not rectangular boxes but rather likeMC Filter Suggestion schematic, preferably with DCR included on schematic , just like TI does on their SMPS Power designs

The COM pin is the common output, what the +24V and -24V are referenced to.  Without it, you don't have a +-24V output, you have a 48V output.
The schematic you posted shorted both Vouts to COM and will only result in failure. I suggest picking a part with a datasheet that includes typical usage so you may copy from that.

Hi, thanks a lot for your help. I updated my circuit in my question, could you help me check if it is correct and if further modifications are needed? Thanks a lot.

You should consider adding filter circuit if you are worrying about EMC. Otherwise you don't need to add those components and your circuit looks just fine. COM is common as GND. So, you should connect -24V and +24V separately to COM through some capacitors. Your current conenction is just a short circuit and you should avoid that.

Hi, thanks a lot for your help. I updated my circuit in my question, could you help me check if it is correct and if further modifications are needed? Thanks a lot.

Hello, I thought you were looking for a simple solution and I guess I was not wrong. All the details suggested by D.A.S. are correct. If you are designing a professional circuit, you should consider adding what he said, even more details will come out. But I thought that you are designing a simpler circuit for testing purposes. If so, what I said before will be enough for you, but if you are designing a professional circuit, I suggest you follow what D.A.S. said.

Hi, yes, I only used this circuit for testing purposes, and I will later convert my ±24V output to ±20V. I just wanted to make sure that my circuit can correctly produce ±24V output.
